# mysql unique index based on joined data

Tags: mysql, unique-index

I have a users and a safes table

users:
id, company_id

safes:
id, user_id, location_id

I want to make sure that a location_id is unique within a company_id. Is there some way to do this through the user_id or do I have to add the company_id to the safes_table?

I.e. is there some kind of unique index that can account for a join? I am also open to any other solution that is DB based.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
SELECT company_id
FROM
(SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) count
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT company_id, location_id
FROM safes
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id = safes.user_id) comp_loc_pair
GROUP BY company_id) loc_count_by_comp
WHERE count > 1
```

which lists the companies with more than one location, this

```
SELECT cle, TypeContact
FROM
(SELECT cle, TypeContact, COUNT(*) count
FROM
(SELECT cle, TypeContact 
FROM img_images 
LEFT JOIN consu_lien 
ON consu_lien.NumRelation = img_images.Cle) comp_loc_pair
GROUP BY cle, TypeContact) comp_loc_counts
WHERE count > 1
```

which shows the companies and locations paired more than once, or do you want to check for a specific location_id and company_id ?